# Angular 1.2.0-rc.3 Directive Priority Change Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this code example that uses Angular 1.2 RC2 and everything works fine, you click on the handle to toggle the display of the content and the controller and directive have seperate scopes as intended:

http://plnkr.co/edit/e3XAZuhSMAxmkWzKKM39?p=preview

Now I upgraded to Angular RC3 yesterday and now the functionality does not work as it stands in the plunker, I get the error the specific requires generic which is can't find.  Going through the change log, I though this might have to do with this breaking change:

`$compile: due to 31f190d4, the order of postLink fn is now mirror opposite of the order in which corresponding preLinking and compile functions execute`

To fix this they either suggest converting the post linking to a  pre linking (which I can do since my post linking needs access to the scope which is not available in the pre linking) or to decrease the priority of the directive.  So this plunker does that and functionality does work:

http://plnkr.co/edit/arP3aruH8HEdiwFg6mWp?p=preview

However there is a major issue and that is now because specific has a higher priority, the isolate scope that generic needs is no longer being created so now contentVisible is on the controller scope which is not good.

Now I could just move the scope: {} from the generic directive to the specific directive however it should be possible to use the generic directive by itself and if I did it would attached to whatever scope it is part of and not its own (which would make it impossible to have multiple instance of this directive, which is way it needs its own scope).

The only thing I can think of is to add a directive, called something like isoScope, make sure it has a very high priority, and have it define scope: {}.  Then if I need to use generic by itself, I just have to make sure to also add the isoScope directive to make sure it has an isolate scope.  Like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1NYHpUcPFWEbAzvkCeRH?p=preview

Now I am hoping there is a better way to accomplish what I am looking for without the isolateScope directive.  Am I missing a way of that this without that?

**UPDATED EXAMPLE**

So here is another plunker that includes hopefully better examples of what I am trying to convey (still has virtually no styles but should not be needed to get the point across):

http://plnkr.co/edit/KtRMa1c9giDrhi1Rqyho?p=preview

I have 3 directives:

- expander
- notification
- isolateScope

The expander directive only adds functionality to be able expander and collapse content, nothing more.  This functionality is something that should be able to be used alone or with another directive (which is why it has a controller).

The notification directive is used to display notification however since we don't want to display the notifications all the time, we use it with the expander directive so that the user can toggle the display of the actually notifications (similar to how stackoverflow.com does it  in the top left).

While I imagine the expander would most likely be used with another directive it should be possible to use alone and that is where the isolateScope directive comes into play.  Since the expander directive adds data to the scope and you may want to have multiple expanders on the same page, it needs to have an isolate scope in order to work.  Now on a users profile page you have have data like developer key and address that you don't really need to display all the time so lets have the user control that.  I have the isolate scope to be able to control both of those independently because without the isolate scope, both of them would be on the same scope and be controlled by the same instance on contentVisible.

I just don't see anyway with how directives now run in 1.2.0 RC3 to be able to accomplish this without that isolateScope directive (though I would be happy to be proven wrong).

Comment: Maybe you could clarify this a lot more. It's quite confusing what you are really going for. Is it: "I want to add a directive that uses a template and then I want a second directive that runs after the first and modifies the template from the first"? Just writing that seems wrong fundamentally, but it seems like what you are trying to do. Maybe you could give a real-world example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code so that it does what I think you want (at a minimum this works the way your old code does, but under rc3 as you wanted):  http://plnkr.co/edit/nsq4BGAih3lfNmS2mLP7?p=preview

But I made quite a few changes and a significant architectural change so let me know if this moves away from the spirit of what you're trying to achieve.

I think the gist of the issue was that your two directives (`generic` and `specific`) were tightly coupled around `contentVisible` which created a complex dependency that resulted in you having to very carefully manage invocation timing.   My approach was to **decouple the two directives**- encapsulating `contentVisible` within `generic`.  This allows `generic` and `specific` to instantiate fully independently. So you're not dependent on any invocation timing.  And **thus the directive priority change no longer has any impact on this code**.  So, one big win with the solution I propose is it should be robust against further changes by the Angular team.

Specifically, I moved the template in to the same directive (`generic`) as the controller which manages `contentVisible` .  This way the **controller that changes `contentVisible` lives on the same scope as the template which uses it**.

Now `specific` just calls over to the `required:` `generic` controller to toggle visibility (effectively as a setter function).

I also moved the `ng-class` assignment into the template in order to encapsulate that change within one place (the template) and so you don't need jquery or a `link:`/`compile:` on `generic`.

Comment: Yea, that moves away from what I was looking for.  I have added another plunker example using better naming to hopefully convey my issue and what I am looking for.

Comment: That does help.  I think this is complicated because you're trying to get the directives to do more than DOM manipulation.  You could decouple the directives from each other by moving your decision making up into mainCtrl (or you might want a new ngController that covers just the region of the page these directives live in).  Then you can get back down to two directives, each with their own limited responsibilities and both talking to your controller (not directive controller, but an ngController).

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding you correctly.  With the way I have things setup, to add expanding functionality I just need to add the expander and isolateScope directives to the html element and make sure they have an element with handle and content classes (only html changes). If I understand what you are saying, I would have to create a new ngController for each page (section) where I want this functionality which seems like a lot of duplication (unless I don't understand what you are saying).

Comment: You could have mainCtrl handle this.  Or you can add a new ngController.  My overall point being that you're trying to get directives to do more than angular really expects them to.  So you're having to work extra hard (I use the "trying to hammer a nail with a screwdriver" analogy-  you can make it work, but it's a pain).  The decision making you want to do more easily fits into an ngController or even a service.  Then you'll have a nice MVC structure which should be easier to maintain.  And it shouldn't be more duplication- just moving the pieces around.

Comment: If you can find time to modify my code with what you are trying to say that would be helpful. I don't know what parts you would move to a ngController or service where you would not have code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression. A fix is in the works: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4431

Comment: Well it looks like the fix is for those specific directives so I don't think it is a regression, it seems like it is more of an intended change (they just didn't update all their code to account for the change).  I have added another plunker example using better naming to hopefully convey my issue and what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have problem, looks very close to your. So if anything will change want to be notified.
My task: I have contact, that could be shown in defferent ways (very common task), but difference between views is in templates, whereas help functions and preparations are same, so I need generic directive for all views.

What I found:
 1. in rc2 it works fine in rc3 unstable
 2. in rc3 it could work same only when template is inline, but not when it is templateUrl (even if cached)

So I created two planks **[rc2 version](http://plnkr.co/edit/plEiMBJuWauy3d2dsysL?p=preview)** and **[rc3 version](http://plnkr.co/edit/spbtxYGicWkB7iJtzoW1?p=preview)**.

Hope this will help.